# Mock a function of an attribute Python

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-mock

I have here:

```
class Authentication(MethodView):

    @staticmethod
    def make_payload(identity):
        iat = datetime.utcnow()
        exp = iat + timedelta(seconds=300)
        nbf = iat + timedelta(seconds=0)
        identity = identity.key.urlsafe()
        return {'exp': exp, 'iat': iat, 'nbf': nbf, 'identity': identity}
```

which is based on JWT. I want to mock `identity.key.urlsafe()` to return `1` which is a user id:

```
def test_make_payload(self):
    def get_urlsafe():
        return self.user_id

    now = datetime.utcnow()
    mock_identity = MagicMock()
    mock_identity.key.return_value = MagicMock(urlsafe=get_urlsafe)
    payload = Authentication.make_payload(mock_identity)
```

Right now, everything works except my mock. The goal was for it to return `1`:

```
ipdb> payload
{'identity': <MagicMock name='mock.key.urlsafe()' id='4392456656'>, 'iat': datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 22, 21, 34, 41, 605698), 'nbf': datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 22, 21, 34, 41, 605698), 'exp': datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 22, 21, 39, 41, 605698)}
ipdb> payload['identity']
<MagicMock name='mock.key.urlsafe()' id='4392456656'>
```

How can I mock this nested call to make `urlsafe` return 1 in my mock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like you want to set the `side_effect` of your mock to be `get_urlsafe`:

```
def test_make_payload(self):
    def get_urlsafe():
        return self.user_id

    now = datetime.utcnow()
    mock_identity = MagicMock()
    mock_identity.key.urlsafe.side_effect = get_urlsafe
    payload = Authentication.make_payload(mock_identity)
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock):

> side_effect: A function to be called whenever the Mock is called. See the side_effect attribute. Useful for raising exceptions **or dynamically changing return values**. The function is called with the same arguments as the mock, and **unless it returns DEFAULT, the return value of this function is used as the return value**.